# Is there a way to name a Processor in Kafka Streams DSL in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I’ve been trying to name a KStream using Kafka Streams DSL in Scala but I cannot find a way to name a processor in `org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream.Consumed`.
Although there is a java method `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed#as` but it throws an exception. Does anyone knows what can be done?

```
ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: [B, and value: [B.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: [B, and value: [B.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:146)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:216)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:85)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:678)
    at ...
```

EDIT:
The code that I used:

```
val someEvents = builder
  .stream[String, String]("some_events")
(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed.as("some_event_stream"))
```

The code I should've used:

```
val someEvents = builder
  .stream[String, String]("some_events")
(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed.as("some_event_stream")
  .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
  .withValueSerde(Serdes.String()))
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with names (which you do with Named objects. The error is referring to your Serde objects. Can you please show more of the code?

Comment: Oh, you were right, the problem was that I used java method Consumed#as without explicitly providing Serdes.

Comment: So, you fixed the problem? If so, put the answer below rather than edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Initial code:

```
val someEvents = builder
    .stream[String, String]("some_events")
  (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed.as("some_event_stream"))
```

I made two mistakes:

1. Put  `Consumed` parameter in a separate line. (todo needs explanation why it doesn't work in Scala)
2. Used Java method `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed.as` and didn't provide SerDes.

This works:

```
val someEvents = builder.stream[String, String]("some_events")(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Consumed.as("some_event_stream").withKeySerde(Serdes.String()).withValueSerde(Serdes.String()))
```

Comment: Explanation of code would help other users to understand the difference.